# using with - how to know which variables are within the context

Tags: python, kivy

In [this Kivy code](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html):

```
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        userdata = touch.ud
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d/2, touch.y - d/2), size=(d, d))
            userdata['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
```

Apparently `Color` and `d` and `Ellipse` are within the namespace of `self.canvas`, but how does Python know that `userdata` is not within that same namespace?

Comment: `Color` and `Ellipse` have both been `import`ed by the line `from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse`. I think you've misunderstood the `with` statement - it has nothing to do with namespaces. A quick Google gives [several](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) [online](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) [tutorials](http://python.about.com/od/gettingstarted/qt/py25WITH.htm) on what `with` is for, as well as [the official docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer got a bit lengthy, so here's the summary:

1. `with self.canvas` defines the currently **active canvas** for the following code block.
2. All drawing instructions like `Color` or `Ellipse` draw on the active canvas.

Namespaces don't really have anything to do with it, it's the context that matters (see below).

The `with` statement allows you to use so called [context managers](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html).

The syntax is like this

```
with thing [as foo]:
```

where `thing` usually is a function decorated with the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator. What exactly a context manager does depends on how `thing` is implemented.

But what it doesn't do is make variable magically appear in your scope. A reference to the context may be obtained by the optional `as foo` clause, but that's it. `Color` and `Ellipse` in your example are coming from somewhere else (probably imports?).

In order to find out what exactly the context manager in the `with self.canvas` line does, you should look at the [API documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas) or the [source code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L470) for `kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas`.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the tutorial:

> By using the with statement with it, all successive drawing commands
>   that are properly indented will modify this canvas. The with statement
>   also makes sure that after our drawing, internal state can be cleaned
>   up properly.

So the **use** of `Color` and `Ellipse` affects `self.canvas`, but they're not defined in any way by the with statement.

Looking at the source code, this is how it works:

```
def class CanvasBase(InstructionGroup):
    def __enter__(self):
        pushActiveCanvas(self)

    def __exit__(self, *largs):
        popActiveCanvas()
```

`__enter__` and `__exit__` define what happens if a context manager is entered (before the first line of indented code after the `with` statement) and exited.

In this case, the canvas simply gets pushed onto a **stack** that defines the currently active canvas (and popped from it if the context manager is exited).

In `kivy.graphics.instructions.Instruction`, the apparent base class for all drawing instructions, the [parent is set to the currently active canvas](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L52):

```
self.parent = getActiveCanvas()
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Color` and `Ellipse` are imported from `kivy.graphics` a little higher in the code:

```
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
```

To answer your question about namespaces, python doesn't need to "know" what namespace it's getting variables from at all. It has very simple namespace rules compared to languages like Java, which search function, object, class, global, and package scopes one after the other. Python has one global namespace (per module) and a stack of local namespaces (e.g. nested functions can get at the variables from outer functions). It just goes down the list of scopes until it finds the variable name in question.

The `with` statement above has special meaning, but I think even `with` can't implicitly introduce new variables into the local scope (it can introduce one variable explicitly with the `as` clause, though).